# Overlapped grobs generated by arrangeGrob when view from RStudio and knit to PDF

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr, gridextra, r-grid

I'm using RStudio under windows 10.
I want to generate a PDF report.
Below is a sample code showing the problem.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
x <- data.frame(x=c(1:100), y=c(1:100))
x_t1 <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 1)
x_t2 <- data.frame(a = 2, b = 2)
x_t3 <- data.frame(a = 3, b = 3)
x_grobs <- list(
  textGrob("text 1"),
  textGrob("text 2"),
  tableGrob(x_t1),
  textGrob("text 4"),
  tableGrob(x_t2),
  textGrob("text 6"),
  tableGrob(x_t3),
  ggplotGrob(ggplot(x, aes(x, y))+geom_point())
)
x_heights <- c(rep(1, 7), 14)
x_arrgorb <- arrangeGrob(grobs=x_grobs,
                         ncol = 1,
                         heights = x_heights)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(x_arrgorb)
```

The output view from my computer is like below:
[image: output of the code]

You can see that though grobs are arranged in sequence and heights as expected, they are heavily overlapped.
When I knit it to an A4 size PDF, the result is similar. All grobs squeezed on the top half of the page, leave most spaces empty:
[image: pdf output]

I tried to set the viewport but did not end up with difference. I think it seems to be related to the plotting area, which has a fixed size, and all grobs are squeezed to fit in this plotting area. I don't know how to adjust this, or if this is the root cause. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: I'm assuming you are putting your plotting code in an Rmarkdown chunk - you can change the figure size for an individual chunk like `\`\`\`{r chunkname, fig.height=10, fig.width=8}`. I think the units for the figure size are inches by default.

Comment: @Marius That solves my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To change the figure size so there is room for the plot when rendering to PDF, use the chunk options for your plotting code chunk and change `fig.height` and `fig.width`:

````
```{r chunkname, fig.height=10, fig.width=8}
<plotting_code>
```
````

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be with the definition of the `x_heights`.  The first two grob are text and should have height 1 and then the first `tableGrob` is plotted with height 2.  Edit the `x_heights` as

```
x_heights <- c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 14)
```

The resulting plot I get is:

[image]